# python and Pandas: min and max value of Day 30 to Day 60 in rollling method uisng groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

how to get max and min of column of a dataframe in pandasof days between Day 60 and Day 90 , Day 30 and Day 60, Day 1 and Day 30. It has to be in rolling form and using groupby.

I tried with iloc and loc.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks an example, but you can certainly combine [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
# set up dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2023-03-10', '2023-05-31', freq='D'),
                   'value': range(83)})

# compute groups of 0-30, 30-60, 60-90 days after min date
group = pd.cut(df['date'].sub(df['date'].min()).dt.days,
               [0, 30, 60, 90], right=True)

# aggregate
out = df.groupby(group)['value'].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Output:

```
          min  max
date              
(0, 30]     1   30
(30, 60]   31   60
(60, 90]   61   82
```

If you rather want a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) min/max on 30 days (but this gives you all combinations: 1-30, 2-31, 3-32, etc. until 61-90):

```
df.set_index('date').rolling('30D').agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Output:

```
           value      
             min   max
date                  
2023-03-10   0.0   0.0
2023-03-11   0.0   1.0
2023-03-12   0.0   2.0
2023-03-13   0.0   3.0
2023-03-14   0.0   4.0
...          ...   ...
2023-05-27  49.0  78.0
2023-05-28  50.0  79.0
2023-05-29  51.0  80.0
2023-05-30  52.0  81.0
2023-05-31  53.0  82.0

[83 rows x 2 columns]
```